# DATA BACKUP from SQL Server Express to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Can I restore the backup data from SQL Server Express to SQL Server, both 2012 versions?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The database format is identical across all editions. An Express Edition database for sure can be restored on a non-Express Edition (you fail to mention whether is a Standard or an Enterprise Edition). The other way around it may be subject to restrictions, Express Edition will refuse to attach or restore a database that:

- exceeds the size limitation of Express Edition
- contains Enterprise Edition only features, like partitioned tables. On SQL Server 2012 anything from [`sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-persisted-sku-features-transact-sql)  will block an Express Edition. This restriction was lifted on SQL Server 2016 SP1.

It is important that both servers (the Express Edition and the non-Express one) be at the same version.

Comment: + 1 for .It is important that both servers (the Express Edition and the non-Express one) be at the same version.